# Generating a nice URL with tag helpers in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

How can I generate a nice URL with tag helpers?

For example:

```
 <a asp-controller="Article" 
    asp-action="FilterByTag" 
    asp-route-tagId="@tag.Id" 
    title="@tag.Description">
         <span class="badge badge-dark">@tag.Title</span>
 </a>
```

This code generate a URL like `/Article/FilterByTag?tagId=2`

But I would like to have `/Article/FilterByTag/tagId=2` or `/Article/FilterByTag/2`

How can I generate this URL by using tag helpers?

Comment: Use attribute routing on the action `[Route("Article/FilterByTag/{tagId}")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute routing on the action like `[Route("Article/FilterByTag/{tagId}")]`

Or for example

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ArticleController : Controller {

    //...other actions

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("FilterByTag/{tagId}")] // Matches GET Article/FilterByTag/2
    public IActionResult FilterByTag(int tagId) {
        //...

        return View();
    }    
}
```

That way, when the action is referenced from tag helpers the generated link will map to the route template for the action and return the desired format like `Article/FilterByTag/2`

> Attribute routing requires more input to specify a route; the conventional default route handles routes more succinctly. However, attribute routing allows (and requires) precise control of which route templates apply to each action.

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)